# how do I properly sign a bitclout tx in golang vs typescript?

Tags: typescript, go, cryptography, bitcoin

I have a working example in [typescript](https://github.com/bitclout/identity/blob/680c584e197eb086e63f0ba12e8142882c2849da/src/app/signing.service.ts#L41):

```
  signTransaction(seedHex: string, transactionHex: string): string {
    const privateKey = this.cryptoService.seedHexToPrivateKey(seedHex);

    const transactionBytes = new Buffer(transactionHex, 'hex');
    const transactionHash = new Buffer(sha256.x2(transactionBytes), 'hex');
    const signature = privateKey.sign(transactionHash);
    const signatureBytes = new Buffer(signature.toDER());
    const signatureLength = uvarint64ToBuf(signatureBytes.length);

    const signedTransactionBytes = Buffer.concat([
      // This slice is bad. We need to remove the existing signature length field prior to appending the new one.
      // Once we have frontend transaction construction we won't need to do this.
      transactionBytes.slice(0, -1),
      signatureLength,
      signatureBytes,
    ]);

    return signedTransactionBytes.toString('hex');
  }
```

and converting to golang I wrote:

```
func signTransaction(seedHex, transactionHex string) string {
  privateKey := seedHexToPrivateKey(seedHex)
  transactionBytes, _ := hex.DecodeString(hexString)
  first := sha256.Sum256(transactionBytes)
  transactionHash := fmt.Sprintf("%x", sha256.Sum256(first[:]))

  signature, _ := privateKey.Sign([]byte(transactionHash))
  signatureBytes := signature.Serialize()

  signatureLength := make([]byte, 8)
  binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(signatureLength, uint64(len(signatureBytes)))

  buff := []byte{}
  buff = append(buff, transactionBytes[0:len(transactionBytes)-1]...)
  buff = append(buff, signatureLength...)
  buff = append(buff, signatureBytes...)

  return fmt.Sprintf("%x", buff)
}
```

It's very close I think. I get back all sorts of interesting error messages when submitting and trying to adjust stuff. But it's not working like the typescript one is. Anyone see any errors? FYI privateKey is *btcec.PrivateKey which is ecdsa.PrivateKey and the signture Serialized is from https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd/blob/master/btcec/signature.go#L40

Comment: It is hard to say from the code alone. But I would recommend to look at the tx bytes in hex and to double-check by hand if they still comply with TxBinaryMap from bitcoin wiki: https://en.bitcoin.it/w/images/en/e/e1/TxBinaryMap.png. That way you might spot what is missing

Comment: thanks! As work around I'm trying to run v8 js inside golang https://bitclout.com/posts/bd504099b60133eaa8ca3e815fd7ee40179cb6a318e803fbb21253153886e1f7

Comment: hahah that is awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That signature error is because the signature is X9.62 which uses ASN.1 to encode both value R and S. If the random value R or the signature S starts with a 1 bit it will be interpreted as a negative value according to the BER/DER encoding of an ASN.1 INTEGER.

As R is randomized and S depends on it they will sometimes error when the integer is not encoded correctly. If the first / leftmost and most significant bit is 1 then a `00` byte should be prefixed to it, so it makes a positive signed big endian value.

Note that the size of the encoded integer value is therefore dynamic as well, it is incorrect to use too many bytes for it.

---

To go from a statically sized, big endian R and S value you should first remove all `00` valued bytes from the left hand side, and then add one back again if the first byte value is `0x80` or higher (assuming unsigned bytes, obviously). This function is commonly referred to as O2ISP (octet-string to integer primitive), taken from the RSA PKCS#1 specifications where it is mathematically described. [Here on Cryptography is a helpful qustion that is a bit more in depth](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/37537/1172)

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

https://github.com/indutny/elliptic/blob/master/lib/elliptic/ec/signature.js#L139

That ^ toDER is correct and this:

https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd/blob/master/btcec/signature.go#L40

is not so now I have:

https://github.com/andrewarrow/clout-cli/blob/main/keys/hdkey.go#L48

which I ported from JavaScript to go and it's working!

Comment: plot thickens! I try and post message with cli and get "signature R is negative" then I try again and get "signature S is negative" and then the 3rd time it works! WTF?

Comment: update: this is now calling https://github.com/andrewarrow/clout-cli/blob/3548df87609fbc4a1b7c2faf213e404bf53cb75a/keys/v8.go#L9 js in go

Comment: if anyone wants to answer this question better with that js correctly converted to golang, i will give you a star.